# Error while properties set up in "Send Email" step in CRM 2013 process

Tags: workflow, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I am using Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2013 On-Premise. I am facing with the issue while I am trying to set up any dynamic value to body section of "Send Email" step in CRM 2013 process.
Here is steps to reproduce in screenshot form:

1)[image: First step]

2)[image: Second step]

3)[image: Third step]

and stack trace:

```
[2014-05-13 15:40:23.325] Process: w3wp |Organization:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |Thread:   31 |Category: Platform |User: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |Level: Error |ReqId: 0ceffee7-ec5f-4823-a0ce-b2ccb55a910d | ExceptionConverter.ConvertMessageAndErrorCode  ilOffset = 0x23B
>System.Xml.XmlException: Microsoft Dynamics CRM has experienced an error. Reference number for administrators or support: #3AE9E085: System.Xml.XmlException: '&' is an unexpected token. The expected token is '"' or '''. Line 1, position 110.
>   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
>   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseAttributes()
>   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElement()
>   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElementContent()
>   at System.Xml.XmlLoader.LoadNode(Boolean skipOverWhitespace)
>   at System.Xml.XmlLoader.LoadDocSequence(XmlDocument parentDoc)
>   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(XmlReader reader)
>   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.LoadXml(String xml)
>   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.Platform.WorkflowLibrary.PropertyExpressionBuilder.CreateDynamicExpression(WorkflowStep workflowStep, WorkflowAttributeType attributeType, String propertyValue, Boolean isEmailBody)
>   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.Platform.WorkflowLibrary.PropertyExpressionBuilder.CreateExpression(WorkflowStep workflowStep, XmlNode propertyNode, String propertyValue, WorkflowAttributeType attributeType, Boolean isEmailBody)
>   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.Platform.WorkflowLibrary.PropertyExpressionBuilder.CreateExpression(WorkflowStep workflowStep, String entityName, String xml)
>   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.WebServices.WorkflowWebService.UpdateSendEmailStep(String activityId, String entityId, String emailXml, String descriptionXml)
```

Please, help me with this problem! Thank you in advance!

Comment: Which is the name of the Account?

Comment: At what time error occurs? In the Email template design window or the time process runs?

Comment: @Jorge, no, it wasn't start on Account record.

Comment: @Scorpion, error occurs after I have clicked Save and Close in Send Email Properties window (step 2 in description), when I go back to Process Information window (step 3 in description).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The issue was resolved by changing browser. All steps to reproduce were done in Chrome browser. I have tried it in Firefox and it works fine.

Comment: I also faced similar issues and everything worked fine in IE.